# incorrect debian install package for pr2_object_manipulation stack?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've installed pr2_object_manipulation with debian package installation

sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pr2-object-manipulation

and this also installed other dependencies e.g. tabletop_collision_map_processing, robot_self_filter_color, tabletop_object_detector, ....

However, the automatically installed dependencies are in old versions. I've checked tabletop_collision_map_processing package, the message type of service is

```
# a list of clusters and database models, directly as produced by the detector
# note that it is possible to not set the Table inside here (leave its
# extents set to zero), in which case it does not get added to the environment
tabletop_object_detector/TabletopDetectionResult detection_result

# whether the current collision models should be reset before adding new models
bool reset_collision_models

# whether the current list of models attached to the robot should be reset
bool reset_attached_models

# what tf frame the results should be returned in
# if empty, results will be in the same frame as the input 
string desired_frame
```

which belongs to [fuerte_old](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte_old/api/tabletop_collision_map_processing/html/srv/TabletopCollisionMapProcessing.html) version

the [new one](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tabletop_collision_map_processing/html/srv/TabletopCollisionMapProcessing.html) should be like following:

```
tabletop_object_detector/TabletopDetectionResult detection_result
bool reset_collision_models
bool reset_attached_models
bool reset_static_map
bool take_static_collision_map
string desired_frame
.....
```

this causes the demo/tutorial code for "write a simple pick and place application" fails to compile.
Could someone update this debian package? or help me to update it so that the new tutorial code can be run??

Thank you!!

Edit 01: the tutorial code is [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Pick%20and%20Place%20Application)
in which there are several unknown members used:

```
// defined in python - line 235 of file _TabletopCollisionMapProcessing.py -> fuerte also has this file
    processing_call.request.reset_static_map = true;
....
processing_call.request.take_static_collision_map = true;

.....
pickup_goal.desired_approach_distance = 0.1;
pickup_goal.min_approach_distance = 0.05;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48195/incorrect-debian-install-package-for-pr2_object_manipulation-stack??/) by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2012-11-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-13**:
It makes it hard to answer your questions when you distribute all relevant information over several questions instead of editing your original question. Also, I cannot find the code you have used. In the tutorial, slots such as `take_static_collision_map` don't seem to be used.

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-11-13**:
Thank you for the answer! Ive compiled the tutorial code successfully. The code and installed dependencies are electric version. The mistake was I used the fuerte  tutorial code which evokes unknown members. Coz' in my browser, I can still print to see the tut code of fuerte version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see a tutorial for fuerte or groovy, only for electric. And in the electric tutorial, there is no reference to `take_static_collision_map` if I can trust my browser's search functionality. Either try to use the electric code or comment out the offending lines.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0